# C# asp.net Upload massive Files kills all log in session

Tags: c#, asp.net

Every Time I upload massive files to the web server. It's kills all log in session for my web site. Is there a reason why user is getting kick off the site? Below is an example of my codes behind the aspx page.

```
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int runCount = 100;      

    for (int i = 0; i < runCount; i++)      
    {
        string path = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + @"\test\test\test\foo" + i + ".txt";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(i);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: It can be for your session timeout. Check your file's size also. It's different to upload 100 files of 1Kb each, instead of 10 files of 20 Mb each. Try to find out an async solution.

Comment: If your application is crashing, it will recycle the app pool, which also kills any in-memory objects, such as Session.  However, you should never use Session for authorization, so even if this happens you should not be "kicked off the site".  If you are using session, stop doing that, and use FormsAuthentication or Asp.net Identity instead.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch even when I don't use session for authorization, it still kills every user on the web site. 

Below is my orginal codes




        if (Session["loggedIn"] == null || Session["UserType"].ToString() != "Admin")
        {
           //do somethign
           
        }

Comment: Yes, that is using session for authorization, and is the absolute wrong way to do it.  It's insecure, and you are at the mercy of the session, which IIS can kill whenever it wants to.  Use a cookie based authentication like FormsAuthentication or IdentityFramework.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch I figured it out. All I needed to do was add a delay in the for loop 
int milliseconds = 50;
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(milliseconds);

Comment: @NARYCHHUN - that may solve your problem for now, but the next time you have an exception thrown you'll have the same problem.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch I hope it does not break later. My application is an integration for an eCommerce website. I have no way of deciding whether to use session or form authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

int runCount = 100;

```
for (int i = 0; i < runCount; i++)      
{
    int milliseconds = 50;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(milliseconds);  

    string path = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + @"\test\test\test\foo" + i + ".txt";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(i);
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, sb.ToString());
}
```

}